# Pessimistic Lock not working Spring Boot Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2 and Spring Data JPA.

I have a service with @Transactional annotation that reads records from repository, then adds records if they don't exist and saves all.
I created a test method that executes the service method 5 times in parallel.
Since I'm using @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) I would expect that one would get the lock when reading Availabilities and the other 4 threads would have to wait until transaction (createReservation) is completed, but instead method is run 5 times and returns no records, so then all threads try to insert a new record and they all fail (except the fist one) with Unique index or primary key violation.
For the test I'm using H2 database.

ReservationService:

```
@Service
public class ReservationService {

  @Autowired
  private AvailabilityService availabilityService;
  @Autowired
  private ReservationRepository repository;

  @Transactional
  public Reservation createReservation(Reservation r) {
    availabilityService.updateAvailability( r);
    return reservationRepository.save( r);
  }
}
```

AvailabilityService:

```
@Service
public class DayAvailabilityService {

  @Autowired
  private AvailabilityRepository availabilityRepository;

  public List<Availability> updateAvailability(Reservation reservation) {
    List<LocalDate> dates = reservation.getStart().datesUntil(reservation.getEnd()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Availability> availabilities = availabilityRepository.findAllById(dates);
    // check availability, add records to this list if a record does not exist
    /// ...
    return availabilityRepository.saveAll(availabilities);
  }
```

}

```
public interface AvailabilityRepository extends JpaRepository<Availability, LocalDate> {

@Override
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
List<Availability> findAllById(Iterable<LocalDate> iterable);
```

}

Availability entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Availability")
public class Availability {

  @Column(name = "Date")
  @Id
  @NotNull
  private LocalDate date;
  @Column(name = "Availability")
  private int availability;
  @Column(name = "MaxAvailability")
  private int maxAvailability;
}
```

This is the test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ReservationServiceIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private ReservationService service;
  @Autowired
  private ReservationRepository repository;

  @Test
  public void testConcurrentCreateReservation() throws InterruptedException {
    Reservation reservation = new Reservation("John", "Doe", "johndoe@mail.com",
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(4), LocalDate.now().plusDays(6), 30);
    runMultithreaded(() -> {
        try {
            service.createReservation(reservation);
        } catch (NoAvailabilityException e) {
            System.out.println("no availability.");
        }
    }, 5);

    long count = repository.count();
    assertEquals(3, count);

  }

  public static void runMultithreaded(Runnable  runnable, int threadCount) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Thread> threadList = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < threadCount; i++) {
        threadList.add(new Thread(runnable));
    }

    for( Thread t :  threadList) {
        t.start();
    }

    for( Thread t :  threadList) {
        t.join();
    }
  }
}
```

in the logs I see that a transaction is created for each createReservation method.

```
Getting transaction for [com.company.app.service.ReservationService.createReservation]
```

Then I see 5 logs like this:

```
Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAllById]
```

Then I see the select query executed 5 times, with "for update" at the end. so the locks should be working but I'm not seeing the result I would expect.

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Add your test class to the question pls. (not only the test method, also the before/after methods if have any)

Comment: @Selindek just added the test class, thanks

Comment: @Selindek also note that findAllById returns no records so maybe the issue is that there is nothing to lock, so how can I prevent the error when each thread tries to insert a record with the same ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you want to insert records with the same ID in each thread.

```
// check availability, add records to this list if a record does not exist
```

Locks don't work for new records. You have to lock the whole table somehow. You can either `synchronize` your method if you are absolutely sure that your server will run only one instance or you can create a special table with 'lock-records' and read that record with a lock before you create the new records in the actual table, then release that lock.

First approach is quite simple, but the second one is more fail safe.